# Some of my projects had 300+ commits, now how do I show those commits in the contribution graph?

Tags: git, github

How can I add the last few months of commits to the contribution graph, which commits don't show in the contribution graph?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+count+contribution

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to merge those commits into your master/main branch?

I have experienced the same problem, it got fixed when i merged my branches into master/main branch and then all the commits appear in the contribution path.

I suggest you to do that.

Comment: Yes, merged and pushed those commits to my main branch but not showing in contribution graph.